# Inputting R ggplot figure into LaTeX document

Tags: r, pdflatex

I'm relatively new to this, so possibly a duplicate question, but I am trying to use `library(tikzDevice)` to add a ggplot figure to a LaTeX document as per this guidance: http://techxhum.dk/ggplot-latex-via-tikz/

This is my code:

```
`Figure_1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Year, y=Numbers2, fill=Level, label = Numbers2)) + 
geom_col()
 tikz('Figure_1.tex', width = 3.5, height=3)`
```

But then when I do `Plot`, the following message is returned:

```
Measuring dimensions of: Year
Running command: "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpG0DaAP\tikzDevice1bac4bdc680b" "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpG0DaAP/tikzDevice1bac4bdc680b/tikzStringWidthCalc.tex"
Measuring dimensions of: \char78
Running command: "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error -output-directory "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpG0DaAP\tikzDevice1bac3435464e" "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpG0DaAP/tikzDevice1bac3435464e/tikzStringWidthCalc.tex".....
```

And it just keeps going and going. I'm not sure if I've installed the packages incorrectly, but any advice on this would be most helpful.